# How to get a session value from a second table?

Tags: php

I have two tables for the users; a login table and the user profile table.

I want to compare a value from 'userprofiletable' to another value from another table called posts. If the value is equal, it shows a list.

I have the following code. The problem is that it is not comparing the value in the posts table with the value of the session from user profile table.

Could someone help me please?

```
<?php
$limit = '5';
$dbreq = 'SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `pos` DESC';
$dbdata = mysql_query($dbreq);
while($dbval = mysql_fetch_array($dbdata))
{
  if (($dbval['city'] == $_SESSION['student_city'])) { //checks for last 4 accomodation
    if ($limit >= '1') {
      echo '<tr><td><a href="acomod.php?view='.$dbval['id'].'">'.$dbval['title'].'</a></td></tr>';
      $limit = $limit -'1';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I also want to get the value of userprofiletable and post it in the posts table. For example, when somebody make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit unclear, but I think this is what you want:

```
<?php
$userid = 11542;//Sample uid. You will have to figure this out and set it.
$limit = 5;
$dbreq = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `userid`=".$userid." ORDER BY `pos` DESC LIMIT=".$limit.";";
$dbdata = mysql_query($dbreq);
while($dbval = mysql_fetch_array($dbdata))
{
  if (($dbval['city'] == $_SESSION['student_city'])) { //checks for last 4 accomodation
    echo '<tr><td><a href="acomod.php?view='.$dbval['id'].'">'.$dbval['title'].'</a></td></tr>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: the problem is that is not getting $_SESSION['student_city']) from database to compare

Comment: So 'student_city' is kept in the database, and not in the session?

Comment: my code works already when city and student_city are in the same table, but now they are in diferent tables and is not working, thats the problem

Comment: I think you need to go back to your original post and define the tables you're drawing from and what session variables you start with. The code you provide suggests 'student_city' is already part of your scoped variables.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but there could be two answers:

To reproduce your code, you can do in ONE sql query:

```
$dbreq = 'SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE city="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['student_city']).'"
ORDER BY `pos` DESC
LIMIT 4';
```

If, however, there are two tables, then you need "LEFT JOIN" linking the posts table to the userprofile table

```
$dbreq = 'SELECT p.*, u.*
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN userprofiletable up ON p.UserID=up.UserID
WHERE up.city="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['student_city']).'"
ORDER BY p.pos DESC
LIMIT 4';
```

(UserID in the table above is the name of the field in the posts table and userprofiletable that links the two.)

Comment: I understand, but in the login table i have ID(userid) and in the userprofiletable i have the ID(userid) too (these are linked), and in the posts table i have id too but its the id of post with autoincrement, i dont have the user id in thr posts table so if my useres id is called id and i have already an id(posts id) in posts table how i do that?

Comment: Just change "p.UserID" to be p.TheNameOfTheFieldContainingTheUserID in the "posts" table, and up.TheNameOfTheFieldContainingTheUserID in the "userprofile" table.

Comment: And if you want to get fields from both tables: SELECT p.OneFieldFromPostTable, p.AnotherFieldFromPostTable, up.FieldFromUserProfileTable etc.

And if field names clash then a) rename them (it's bad practice for your "primary key" to be called "ID" as you end up with this confusion - rename as user_id for user _id, then have execatly the same field name in the posts table. Then rename post_id for the posts table.

But, if you have to have is like that, "SELECT p.ID AS PostID, up.ID as UserProfileID" then, un your returning array, $dbval['PostID'] will be the first, and $dbval['UserProfileID']